# Error while trying to sort a list of numbers

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class sorting
{  
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter Input: ");
     String a = S.next();
     int s = Arrays.sort(a);
   }
}
```

I am sorting a list of numbers but  when I compile it gives me this error

```
sorting.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
int s = Arrays.sort(s);
        ^
symbol: variable Arrays
location: class sorting
```

Comment: You haven't imported `java.util.Arrays`, and even if you had that wouldn't turn a String into an int.

Comment: Start from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/)

Comment: You probably want to set up some kind of loop for reading the numbers from the `Scanner`.  Right now, you're only letting the user enter a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.sort() function takes an array as a parameter.
What you are doing is, passing a string as a parameter to it.

While reading using Scanner, keep adding those numbers to an array, and then call Arrays.sort(list).

Here is a link which explains this with an example to help you out:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm

Answer (score 1):

[@user3517318](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22975349/3517265)'s answer is on the right track, but you could also use the scanner to read numbers into a SortedSet, and they will be auto-sorted as they go into the set, no need to sort them yourself. This way you have your list (set) already sorted if System.in is blocking for more input:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Input: ");

Set<Integer> list = new TreeSet<Integer>();

while(s.hasNextInt())
    list.add(s.nextInt());

//then, to iterate over the list, use this:
for(Integer i: list) {
    //do something with i
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  My only criticism is the use of the name `list` for a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because Arrays.sort(String a) doesn't exist. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html